# WCF service library in Visual Basic 2010 express

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

I'm using visual basic 2010 express as my IDE, i need to use WCF to create a client-server system, but i can't find the WCF service library, it's not shown as template and i can't find a place to download it, i've seen a few videos of people with visual studio (not visual basic) using WCF, is that the problem?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used the express versions, but I think you need VS 2010 Web Developer Express to do that.  In any event, why not download [VS 2017 Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15)?  It's free and should have everything you need.  Much better than the Express editions (which died out with 2012, IIRC).

Comment: will try download that version and update my question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like WCF is not available to VB 2010, I'll have to swap to VS